# How to change a .png output from Python to an OpenGL window output?

Tags: python, image

I have a Python code whose output is a .png file. What should I do to get the output in an OpenGL window?
I searched a few places and the closest I got to converting an Image was StringIO() but that didn't seem very helpful.

Comment: how about using glReadPixel()?

Comment: glReadPixel() doesn't work with PNG natively. You would still need to convert it to a compatible format.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need the OpenGL bindings to create an OpenGL window. Try [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/)

The next step is to look at the code. My guess is that some kind of image object is created, then something is drawn onto it and lastly, the image is saved as PNG.

At that point, you need to convert the image data (see the docs for details) into something that PyOpenGL can display. The example at the end of [this page](http://www.geometrian.com/PyOpenGLInfo.php) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to handle the more complex details you could setup your OpenGL using pygame then use

`surface = pygame.image.load(fileobj)`

Where fileobj is any object with a 'file-like' interface. You would need to modify the PNG generator to write to this object rather than a real file.